# Why I can't get the selected function in php/Wordpress to get only one option selected

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't get the selected function in wordpress to append only one option of a select dropdown element. Here is the Function I'm working on, to add an extra field in the user profile edit screen on admin in wordpress:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

<h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="empresa">Empresa</label></th>

                <td><select name="empresa" id="empresa">
                    <?php 
                         $empresa = new WP_Query(array( 
                         'post_type'    => 'negocios'));
                         while($empresa->have_posts()) { 
                         $empresa->the_post(); ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo the_title(false); ?>" 
                             <?php if ( get_user_meta( 'ref_neg', 
                                 $user->ID ) == the_title(false) ) echo '" 
                                 selected="selected"'; ?>>
                             <?php echo the_title(false); ?></option>
                         <?php } ?>
                 </select>

             <span class="description">Por favor elija su empresa.</span>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
<?php }
```

Comment: found a solution myself... <select name="ref_neg" id="ref_neg">
                <?php 
                $userd = get_userdata( $user->ID );
                $empresa = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type'  => 'negocios'));
        while($empresa->have_posts()) { 
        $empresa->the_post(); $title = the_title('','',false); ?>
        
           <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>"<?php echo selected( get_user_meta($user->ID,'ref_neg', true), $title, true ); ?>>
           <?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>
           </option>
           <?php }; ?>
      </select>

Answer (score 0):

found a solution myself...

```
<select>                
    <?php 
        $userd = get_userdata( $user->ID );
           $empresa = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type'   => 
           'negocios'));
            while($empresa->have_posts()) { 
            $empresa->the_post(); $title = 
            the_title('','',false); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>"<?php   
                           echo selected( get_user_meta($user->ID,'ref_neg', 
                           true), $title, true ); ?>>
                           <?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>
             </option>
                <?php }; ?>
</select>
```